# Как сделать так чтобы блок можно было прокручивать только тогда когда я навожу туда стрелку мыши?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animation

Вот такой скрипт который можно прокручивать центральный блок с помощью мыши
just-for-portfolio.gq/vk-structure.html
Но дело в том, что я хочу чтобы его можно было прокручивать только тогда, когда наводишь туда курсор (стрелку) мыши, как например в диалогах вконтакте. Кто знает как это сделать?

Comment: а скрипт тебе на кой, если и css хватает

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Comment: добавьте ваш [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #404040;
}

div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  max-height: 1400px;
  background: #272727;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
  <br/>маша пошла в лес за приключениями
</div>
```